# How to give each field in an array its own variable

Tags: php, pdo

i'm working on a small text based web game for a few friends to play (for nostalgia) but i'm having trouble with the very core of the game, the attacking/defending.

Each player has x amount of each troop type (more can be purchased and will be lost on atk/def)
so far I have a table with troop types and stats and a table with troop qty linked with user id and troop id.

I'm using the user id to get the troop id and qty using;

// Get attacker troop quantities.

```
$i = 0;
$attacker_deets = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM troop_qty WHERE user_id= :attacker_id");
$attacker_deets->bindParam(':attacker_id', $attacker_id);
$attacker_deets->execute();

    $attacker_deets_results = $attacker_deets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($attacker_deets_results as $atk_key=>$atk_result) {
             echo "<pre>"; var_dump($atk_result); echo "</pre>";
        }
```

which outputs;

```
array (size=4)
    'troop_qty_id' => string '1' (length=1)
    'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
    'troop_id' => string '1' (length=1)
    'qty' => string '100' (length=3)

array (size=4)
    'troop_qty_id' => string '2' (length=1)
    'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
    'troop_id' => string '2' (length=1)
    'qty' => string '100' (length=3)
```

I'm then using the troop id to get the troop details;

// get attacker troop details.

```
    $attacker_troop_deets = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM troops WHERE troop_id= :atk_troop_id");
    $attacker_troop_deets->bindParam(':atk_troop_id', $attacker_deets_results[$i]['troop_id']);
    $attacker_troop_deets->execute();
    $returned_results = $attacker_troop_deets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($returned_results as $key=>$result) {
             echo "<pre>"; var_dump($result); echo "</pre>";                
        }
    ++$i;
```

which in total gives me;

```
array (size=4)
  'troop_qty_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'troop_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '100' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  'troop_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'troop_name' => string 'Fist Puncher' (length=12)
  'troop_atk' => string '1' (length=1)
  'troop_def' => string '1' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'troop_qty_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'troop_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'qty' => string '100' (length=3)

array (size=4)
  'troop_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'troop_name' => string 'Stick Waver' (length=11)
  'troop_atk' => string '2' (length=1)
  'troop_def' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Now where i'm stuck is I need to be able to compare the troop_atk of First Puncher with the defence of Stick Waver which is gotten from a different set of duplicate query's getting the defenders details, i also need to be able to multiply and divide the atk and def variables.

so how would i go about achieving this? i would assume i would need to give each field in the array their own variable, but how? i have tried using ${"troop_name" . $i} = $attacker_deets_results[$i]['troop_name']; but it only ever outputs the last entered name.

any help would be amazing. thanks.

Edit: To clear things up a little, my goal is to get the troop qty and multipy it by both atk and def then use these numbers to do some other math with the same fields from the defending player which I'll use to decrease the qty field.

Comment: Is `$i` ever incremented? Seems like its outside a loop in your examples.

Comment: he uses it in bindParam() so it must reference outer loop or something, probably loops through the first results

Comment: Did you look at the `extract()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could modify your code a little and do the following.

Fetch the data about the user's troops in one query:

```
    $results = $conn->query("SELECT troop_qty.user_id as uid, troop.troop_id, troop.troop_name, troop_qty.qty, troop.troop_atk, troop.troop_def FROM troop_qty join troop on troop.troop_id=troop_qty.troop_qty_id WHERE troop_qty.user_id=:attacker_id
```

Create a new array which contains information about all user's troops:

```
$userData = array(
    'id' => $attacker_id,
    'troops' => array());

while (($res = $results->fetch_assoc()) != null) {
    $troopData = array(
        'name' => $res['troop_name'],
        'qty' => $res['qty'],
        'atk' => $res['troop_atk'],
        'def' => $res['troop_def']);

    $userData['troops'][$res['troop_id']] = $troopData;
}
```

As result you would have something like this (vardump($userData)):

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => int 2
  'troops' => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Fist Puncher' (length=12)
          'qty' => string '100' (length=3)
          'atk' => string '1' (length=1)
          'def' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Stick Waver' (length=11)
          'qty' => string '100' (length=3)
          'atk' => string '2' (length=1)
          'def' => string '1' (length=1)
```

I don't know how exactly you want to manipulate the data later on in the game but I think this would ease the work.

Btw. I've thrown away fetchAll() function because I personaly think it is not a good practice to fetch all data into memory and then modify it or do whatever with it. It's a waste of the memory and when you would deal with a big amount of data, at some point that could cause you some troubles.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up for me it's so much easier to understand like this. Though how would I go about calling one of them?  Would it be $userData[troops][1][name] ?

Comment: to get the data about the user's troop the structure is like $userData['troops'][$troopID]. then you will have the array with all the info about requested troop (name, attack, defence, and quantity). If you need to look up by a troop's name (which I think would be a worse way) you can modify while loop and put:

$userData['troops'][$res['troop_name']] = $troopData;

and save troop ID in $troopData. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ah, I need to get the qty and multipy by atk and def then do some other math with the same kind of variables but for the defending player then change the qty based on the math (troop deaths) but as an array newb I'm completely lost.